# What is the difference between $0$ and $\vec{0}$?

Tags: geometry, definition

If we take the approach underlined by Peano axioms, we get:

$$a + (-a) = 0.$$

Likewise, we can get the same thing in Euclidean plane:

$$|AB| + (-|AB|) = 0,$$

where $A$ and $B$ are points, and $|AB|$ is the length of the line segment $AB$ (thus the "operation" $AB - AB$ has no meaning, as we have not ascribed any attributes to the line segment).

On the other hand,

$$\vec{AB} - \vec{AB} = \vec{AB} + \vec{BA} = \vec{0}.$$

Well, what is the difference between $0$ and $\vec 0$ ? I think that a concrete definition of both should clear my confusion up. I understand that $\vec 0$ cannot be used in the same context as $0$ (because the former arises from the definition of vector), but I still don't have in-depth understanding of the concept of $\vec 0$. In Euclidean plane **both $0$ and $\vec 0$ are points, right? So what's the difference then?**

Comment: $\vec{0}$ is the unique vector in Euclidean space such that $\vec{a} + \vec{0} = \vec{0} + \vec{a} = \vec{a}$ for all vectors $\vec{a}$. $0$ is a real number (with the same property in the reals), not a vector. So $0$ is not in the Euclidean plane. One is a vector, one is a real number.

Comment: You wrote "In Euclidean plane **both $0$ and $\vec 0$ are points**", but this is false. $0$ is a point in the real number line, whereas $\vec 0$ is a point in the Euclidean plane.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We sometimes write $\vec{0}$ for the zero vector in a vector space to distinguish it from the $0$ inside the field we are working over. For example, you could write that $0\vec{v}=\vec{0}$.

Actually, $0$ can also be used in vector spaces to denote the $\vec{0}$, because algebraically it is the zero element of the underlying abelian group. This is less specific than the notation in the last paragraph though.

> In Euclidean plane both $0$ and $\vec{0}$ are points, right?

Well, I wouldn't want to say it that blithely, given the context I mentioned above. In the Euclidean plane, things look like ordered pairs $(a,b)$, and we might say that $\vec{0}=(0,0)$ where the $0$ comes from the underlying field (not the plane.) These ordered pairs are *coordinate vectors* yes, meaning that they specify a particular point in the plane.

Answer (score 2):

$\vec{0}$ is a vector while $0$ is a number

Comment: Can you elaborate? I specifically said that I **intuitively** understand what you just stated, but I lack reaffirmation with proper definitions.

Comment: they are differen object which respond to different use and concept so you must distinguish them using different symbols, for example $$\vec{v}-\vec{v}=\vec{0}$$ while $$0 \cdot \vec{v}=\vec{0}$$ but $$\vec{0} \cdot \vec{v}= <\vec{0} , \vec{v}>=0$$